# Is it possible to create a new language that translates into words at least the basic operations of math, to make it easier to understand?

Tags: arithmetic

I was wondering if it's possible to make maths easier to calculate and understand, and more natural for kids and even adults. And then I realized how easy it is for human beings to manipulate words and from them make whole sentences and express complex concepts easily than what we do with maths.

> So my question: Is it possible to create a new language that translates into words at least the basic operations of math? and if it is, how do we make those operations with words?

---

I hope you guys understand my question and that I'm not trying to reinvent math. I'm trying to make it easier for the daily routine and to kids and adults that have been struggling with math as myself.

Sorry for any mistakes I might made, as English isn't my native language.

Comment: at an elementary stage they are already simple enough to grasp, this is due maybe to the last  3 or 4 thousands years of evolution of the human mind

Comment: I don't understand this question.  We already have a language of math in English.  We say "two times two is four", "the cosine of zero is one" etc.

Answer (score 2):

Well, math is... you know, **math**. There are a lot of rigorous formulas that aren't really present in the english language. You could rename numbers, operations, et cetera, but at the end, the math will still exist and stay the same.

For example, $1+1=2$. If you named $1$ as "quing" and $2$ as "quang" and $+$ as "quong", then "quing quong quing is quang" would still be $1+1=2$, just in a different form.

This is what makes language different from math. In math, $1+1=2$, no matter what. But in language, you have interpetations, connotations, and all that sort of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a fundamental misunderstanding here. Language *in general* is often open to manipulation, but the language of mathematics points to a set of unambiguous abstractions, so there's no leeway for much else. You can reword anything in any way you choose, but unless you're simply renaming conventions, you're bound to introduce non-mathematical prose. This is actually why there's a discussion in education about what's known as *disciplinary literacy*: it's important for students of mathematics at almost any level to be able to properly interpret a mathematical text *as a mathematical text*, understand the abstractions, and become literate in mathematical language.

I think what you're actually trying to accomplish is a systematized way of explaining concepts, and while I certainly think that's a laudable goal, I also think what you're looking for lies in the study of mathematics education rather than the language of mathematics itself, since what you're looking for has to do with how best to convey to others the meaning of mathematical language.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you both for take time to answer my question, and i think that what we re dealing its how Stephen Goree said disciplane litteracy. Im gonna keep studying math education because as its is said knowledge is power, thanks again.